# How to insert these unicode symbols u2400 to u2421?

Tags: symbols, unicode

Please how can I insert these unicode symbols in the range u2400 to u2421. They are names of control characters.

You can see them here:
http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf

I could find the package `keystroke` which has very nice keys, but that is not what I want.

Thanks!

--
Edited:

Quoting Marco: "The problem is to find a font that contains these characters."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It mostly depends on your setup. If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec` it all boils down to

```
\newfontfamily{\lowasciifont}{Free Sans}
\newcommand{\lowascii}[1]{{\lowasciifont\char\string"#1}}
```

in the preamble and `\lowascii{2400}` and so on in the document. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\lowasciifont}{Free Sans}
\newcommand{\lowascii}[1]{{\lowasciifont\char\string"#1}}

\begin{document}
\lowascii{2400} \lowascii{2401}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX I don't know of any font that has those symbols. One might conceive to create suitable Type1 fonts from FreeSans, but it's quite a job and probably its easier to fake those symbols with some low level trick.

Here's an example:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand{\lowascii}[1]{\innerlowascii#1\relax}
\def\innerlowascii#1#2#3\relax{%
  $\vcenter{
  \fontsize{4}{4}\sffamily
  \offinterlineskip
  \kern-1.2ex
  \sbox0{#1}\dimen0=\wd0 \box0
  \sbox0{#2}\moveright\dimen0\copy0 \advance\dimen0\wd0
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else\moveright\dimen0\hbox{#3}\fi}$}
```

In the text you can say

```
A \lowascii{NUL} \lowascii{LF} B
```

and get

[image]

Comment: You did a very good job on this explanation. Thanks! I think if I don't find a font, I'll probably do the trick you taught.

Comment: The "Free Mono", "Free Sans" and "Free Serif" fonts have the symbols. Also "Arial Unicode MS".

Comment: Dear @egreg,  can't find more information about free mono and free sans. Google think these words are to wide as keywords. Do you know a place where I can find the name of the symbols inside these fonts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DrBeco The "Free" fonts are already available in TeX Live: they are part of the GNU project.

Comment: Ok, but I still need to know the character name. For example, like in keystrokes package, I can use `\Del`. How can I get the character names for those fonts?

Comment: @DrBeco The `keystrokes` package defines the name. Here we don't have any package. Just use the table you referred to in your question: with the Xe|Lua solution you call them by number, with the low level one you call them by giving the two or three letters.

Comment: Ok, sorry, maybe I'm too stupid to understand that. I just tried `{\fontfamily{freemono}\selectfont\char"u2400}` and got a beautiful error. Is freemono a fontfamily? Thanks again your kind attention.

Comment: @DrBeco Read again my answer: the "Free" fonts are OpenType and directly usable only with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Using xelatex, and your minimal example, I got no errors, no warning, and no text (a blank page). Is there something missing in my system?

Comment: @DrBeco You possibly have a version of FreeSans that hasn't the glyphs. Check in the `.log` file for "Missing character"

Comment: Yep. You got it. So, there is no solution to my problem (but the trick, which is fine) `Missing character: There is no ␁ in font Free Sans/ICU!`

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not how to enter the characters. You enter them as you enter all other characters, which depends on your keyboard layout and editor configuration. Either you enter them directly, you create a mapping for often used ones or you enter the unicode values directly. E.g. in vim you can do this with `<CTRL-V>u<unicode_number>`.

The problem is to find a font that contains these characters.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'll edit the question to include the problem description you gave.